# Visual Studio 2015 Tests Proxy configuration

Tags: testing, networking, proxy, visual-studio-2015, packet-sniffers

Using Fiddler (listening on localhost:8888), I would like to sniff network traffic of the tests executed with VisualStudio 2015.

I would like to sniff only test traffic : I dont want to capture all packets of my host...

I've updated `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` by adding defaultProxy section :

```
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
            <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
        </defaultProxy>
```

This configuration seems work for VisualStudio IDE general application ; example on VS home page I could wee the traffic that load Microsoft news.

But while executing a given test, I dont see network trafic !?
Where VisualStudio test proxy should be setup ?

NB: I ve seen TestSettings feature in visual studio, but there is no way to update proxy settings.